# Using IS NULL in PyMongo

Tags: python, sql, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do an `'d': None` in my pymongo query. But when I do `None`. I am not getting any results.

My SQL:

```
SELECT date, a, vt, b, c, d 
   ,SUM(theSum) AS theSum 
   FROM table
   where date between '2019-07-08' and '2019-08-08' 
   AND a in ( 'abc', 'xyz')
   AND c IN ('qwe')
   AND b IS NOT NULL
   AND (d IN ('yo') OR d IS NULL)
   group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
   order by theSum DESC
   LIMIT 25
```

PyMongo:

```
{'$match': {
                '$and': [{
                    'date': {
                        '$gte': sd,
                        '$lte': ed
                    },
                    'a': { '$in': a },
                    'b': {'$ne': None},
                    'c': { '$in': c },
                },  {
                    '$or': [{
                        'd': {'$in': d}
                    }, {'d': None
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': {
                    'a': '$a',
                    'vt': '$vt',
                    'b': '$b',
                    'c': '$c', 
                    'd': '$d'
                },
                'theSum':{
                    '$sum': '$theSum'
                }
            }
        }, {
            '$project': {
                '_id': 0,
                'a':'$_id.a',
                'vt': '$_id.vt',
                'b': '$_id.b',
                'c': '$_id.c', 
                'd': '$_id.d',
                'theSum': '$theSum'     
            }
        }, {
            '$sort': { 'theSum': -1 }
        }, {
            '$limit': 25
        }
        ])
```

I get 43 records when I query in SQL but 0 when I query the pymongo code. What am I doing wrong in pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use None in your queries - you may want to take a look at your brackets instead - specifically, here:

```
'$or': [{
'd': {'$in': d}
 }, {'d': None
 }]
```

there is a bracket in front of "{'d':  None" rather than after it.